# how modify flask session object when session object is a list

Tags: python, session, flask

I have a Session object as a list, and I would like to update it in the list. I have tried to iterate over the Flask Session object and it worked, but when I tried to modify the value in a Flask Session, it gave me an error.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    if "lenta" not in session:
        session["lenta"] = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
        session["move"] = "X"

    return render_template("game.html", game=session["lenta"], move=session["move"])


@app.route("/play/<int:row>/<int:col>")
def play(row, col):
    for i in session["lenta"]:
        for j in i:
            session["lenta"][i][j] = row, col
            redirect(url_for("index"))
```

I would expect that `session["lenta"][i][j]` will be updated with values Row and Col from HTML, but I get the error:

```
session["lenta"][i][j] = row, col
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Comment: In the future, please don't write your questions in all-caps. It makes it hard to read. I've edited it for you.

Comment: thanks, sorry i first time use stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're iterating over the elements of `session['lenta']` (i.e. `for i in session["lenta"]`), but the elements of session["lenta"] are lists themselves (for example `[None, None, None]`). This is why you get this error.

To solve it, try calling the element you're iterating over, something like this:

```
def play(row, col):
    for el in session["lenta"]:
        for j, _ in enumerate(el):
            el[j] = row, col
            redirect(url_for("index"))
```

See if this works, and good luck!

[Edited for clarification]:
I don't have your whole code, what I've checked on my part is:

```
z = [[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
for vi in z:
    for j,vj in enumerate(z):
        vi[j] = (i,j)
```

(On Python 3.6)

Comment: geting the same error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType. :(

Comment: Edited to call indices in second loop. Tried it on my part and it works.

Comment: im now faceing problem, that it updates the first element of the 2d list, but not others:[[(0, 1), None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]], [[(1, 1), None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]

Comment: Don't know what to say, because I can't see `redirect`... I've only checked the basic loop on the list of lists.